# Allow any input string when class is instantiated without a generic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following class and types:

```
type keyCollection = {
  [key: string]: {
      request: any,
      response: any
  }
}

class myTest<TData extends keyCollection = any> {
  testFunction<
    TInput extends keyof TData, 
    TObject = TData extends keyCollection ? TData[TInput]['request'] : any>(input: TInput, data: TObject) {}
}
```

My goal is, that if this class is instantiated without any generic parameter, the `testFunction` should accept any `string` as it's first parameter, and anything as it's second parameter. Yet, when a generic is passed to the class, it should constrain the values of the `testFunction`.

Here are some test cases:

```
let a: myTest = new myTest();
a.testFunction('test', {}); // works as expected, no generic parameter for the class, thus accepts string as first parameter, and any as second


type testGenericKeyCollection = {
  a: {
    'request': string,
    'response': any
  },
  b: {
    'request': string,
    'response': any
  }
}
let b: myTest<testGenericKeyCollection> = new myTest();
b.testFunction("c", 25); // correctly errors out, as "c" as not a property of 
b.testFunction("a", 25); // why no error here? 25 is type number not type string - also, why no type helping here?
```

As you can see in the comments, the instantiation without generic seems to work in the first test case - the function accepts any string as it's first parameter, and anything as it's second parameter.

As for the second case, it still is ok, when the class is instantiated with a generic type provided, `testFunction` does not accept "c" as it's first parameter anymore, because it is not a property of the provided generic.

Yet, for the third test-case, while it correctly identifies the key from the input, it allows any type as the second parameter, and I can't figure out why. The third test-case should only accept a `string` type as it's second parameter.

Why is this not working the way I am expecting it to work?

Fiddle [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=115#code/C4TwDgpgBA1hIGED2AbFEDGwCWSB2UAvFAN4CwAUFFANpwgBcUAzsAE7Z4DmAuk%20VWpC2EAI4BXCKyYBDPCAA0lIcKlh8zCLPnKoAX0oGKlDChnNmUALYgAKlOAAeWwBEZwGVAgAPYBDwAJpb0yGiYOPhEUHIgAHykun6sAGLieFi4eI661LYAknhg4sBevv5BsPBIAGZQru4yClA5dQDyAEYAVuFR9R6lfoHB8KHoGZEA-HVuHjT5hcU8NADkIhIOyzxQ2nEAFJxFwEzzh00BDccd3VgAlKRGRpToJTJMNvasUXgQAO7Wdg5djcANyUGQAOiSwFS6QieF2yyhyyaJD0IKgAHoMVAfkg2DBLOZSpAsBAAk08EgoFx-BAOBgoGAZGwZFYIH42FBqnioMAABbQUzmZhNfniQkYDAQMDASysDjcaKWarYNifJkstkcppyALReRKliYfABShmiigSC8hwAcVp9IA0iNUGM4VEBNRXglBNRVmJJKxlkx5ZwuEofVA-cx1HhNEH9SBdHpw9R2vwWn71oHg%20xQymhFGY3GdknDE92VA0-8Pk4oXbvo7nWFxnh4sRvn93oCQZR2pCHDCW7sAEQYYdNABMAFZ0VioBg8SIsCgQF42Gw8ZYkMUdZZR8PDZSXoyN5A2KAoDVmhQ%201DB3CRzJx1Bp7PsT8%20avKWuN5yBSIpmnKBsEsS1oDwcQrHaOkoCPXlwGgENFQAWmiFBmCQJoPy-KkwKgAUUDAUN8LpCAJiAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a default type (`TObject = ...`) instead of a type constraint:

```
class myTest<TData extends keyCollection = any> {
  testFunction<
    TInput extends keyof TData, 
    TObject extends TData extends keyCollection ? TData[TInput]['request'] : any>(input: TInput, data: TObject) {}
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=27&pln=28&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAaxhAwgewDYZgYzASzQDs4BeOAb1DjgG0kIAuOAZzACd8iBzAXWaogawuOxgBHAK4w2zAIZEIAGmojRMqMRYx5i1QF9QhkKBwY5LFnAC2EACoywAHjsAROWDlwYADzAwiABMrBnQsXAJiMjgFCAA+SlV-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)

Comment: I was looking for something like this, just didn't think I can do it the way you did!:) let me try it out

Comment: Yes, this works like this. Any change, I could constraint it further, that in case no generic was provided to the class, only strings should be accepted as the first parameter to `testFunction`?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai `TInput extends Extract<keyof TData, string>, ` should work